# Adding delay in sending each mail using phpmail function, while sending mail to 1000 users in all

Tags: php

I want to add a delay of about 30 to 60 seconds between sending of each email to users with phpmail() function. I am taking users email data from table and using while loop and there are about 1000 users in database table. I want there to be a delay in repeating the statement of this while loop, so that every email is sent to next user after that particular user. I am using the the following code:

```
$sql = "select * from users where `user_email` = '$_REQUEST[q]' or `user_name`='$_REQUEST[q]' ";

$rs_results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());   

while ($rrows = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results)) {

$fullname = $rrows['full_name'];
$usermailid = $rrows['user_email'];
$username = $rrows['user_name'];

$message =
"Hello $fullname  \n
Welcome to My Site \n
The rest of the message";

mail($usermailid, "Important Message - from Site Admin", $message,
    "From: \"Mysite Admin\" <auto-reply@mysite.com>\r\n" .
     "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()); 
}
```

The above code sends all emails together to 1000 users in table in one go. I want that there should be delay of 30 to 60 seconds between sending of each and every email

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php. The php sleep function delays the script execution by x seconds.

Comment: sleep() function is not working in my case, when i use sleep() it delays the overall execution of code and the response page opens with a delay and still all the emails are sent together in one-go. but what i wanted to add delay in each time a mail is sent. i.e. delay after every time the while loop is executed in next step. Hope you can understand my problem... please explain me your answer..

Comment: So you are looking for some kind of background processing. The php exec command might help running a second script, but it is blocked on most shared webhosters. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php. Running a cronjob might be also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the sleep function inside the loop?

It might be that, even if you are, the mail() requests are just being stacked up until the script finishes running. But that's the other problem: the time your script takes to run will be 500 to 1000 minutes - longer than the maximum probably allowed by your server.

However, with a cron function you can have that wake up every minute and send one email and terminate.